# Strange behavior of matplotlib's griddata

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a .txt file with values

x1 y1 z1

x2 y2 z2

etc.

With my previous little experience I was trying to draw a contourf, with this code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
from pylab import *

rc('font', family='serif')
rc('font', serif='Times New Roman')
rc('font', size='9')
rc('text', usetex=True)

from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
matplotlib.use('pgf')
fig = plt.figure()
data = np.genfromtxt('Velocidad.txt')
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')


x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

xi = np.linspace(0,3000.0, 400)
yi = np.linspace(0,4.0, 200)
zi = griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi,interp='nn')

CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,200,cmap=plt.cm.jet,rasterized=True)
plt.colorbar()


plt.xlim(0,3000)
plt.ylim(0,4.0)
plt.ylabel(r'$t$')
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.title(r' Contour de $v(x,t)$')
plt.savefig("CampoVel.png", dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

the problem is the output:

[image]

When I see this picture and I look at the data (which is here, [in this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74113228/Velocidad.txt)) and I don't understand those discontinuities in x=750 and x=1875. And those strange vertical lines all over the plot. Looking at the data I would expect something smooth, at least in those positions, but the output obviously isn't. Is this a problem of griddata()? How can I solve it?

I have been told that as my data is regularly spaced on X and Y, I shouldn't use griddata(), but I have looked examples and I can't get the code to work.

Comment: Can you post an example of your input file (or a subset of it) to make your problem reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply reshape your data after loading it and skip the `griddata` thing, doing this:

```
data = data.reshape(81, 201, 3)
x = data[...,0]
y = data[...,1]
z = data[...,2]

CS = plt.contourf(x,y,z,200,cmap=plt.cm.jet,rasterized=True)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

You get this:
[image]